# Serilog - how to customize date in rolling file name?

Tags: c#, serilog

In Serilog, you can easily enable rolling log files:

```cs
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .WriteTo.File("log-.txt", rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day)
    .CreateLogger();
```

This will create a new log file every day in the following format:

- `log-20200214.txt`
- `log-20200215.txt`
- `log-20200216.txt`

**My question:** is it possible to customize where the date is placed in the file name, and to customize how the date is formatted?

e.g. I want the file names to look like this:

- `2020-02-14-log.txt`
- `2020-02-15-log.txt`
- `2020-02-16-log.txt`

I was hoping replacing `"log-.txt"` with `"{Date:yyyy-MM-dd}-log.txt"` would work, but it doesn't.

Comment: use `$"{Date:yyyy-MM-dd}-log.txt"`, then it should work if you have a datefield, if not use instead of Date `DateTime.Now`

Comment: @Isparia this solution doesn't work for me

Comment: i am too expecting the same. but, unfortunately no inbuilt methodology to format it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is not currently supported by the [Serilog.Sinks.File](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-file) sink. If you really want this feature, you can try to [send a pull-request](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-file/pulls), or fork the repository and use your own custom implementation.

Links you might be interested in:

- [Support {Date} for log path](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-file/issues/64)
- [Serilog {Date} format when using RollingFile](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/issues/612)
- [Ability to use DateTime format strings in Rolling File Sinks file names](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-file/pull/84)
- [Support for path by date](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-file/issues/125)

Comment: still not supported, except for the automatically added timestamp when time-based rolling is used?

Comment: Yes, that’s correct

Comment: They already have a placeholder '{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}' for the outputTemplate, why not applying this logic to the filename. Still not supported today unfortunately.