# How roll Serilog text files similar to log4net?

Tags: c#, logging, serilog

I wounder how to setup Serilog.Sinks.File to produce this:

```
log.txt <-- current log
log20200704.txt  <-- rolled over yesterday log
log20200703.txt
```

instead of:

```
log20200705.txt <-- current log
log20200704.txt  <-- rolled over yesterday log
log20200703.txt
```

I am used to such behavior since log4net days.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Serilog - how to customize date in rolling file name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60228026/serilog-how-to-customize-date-in-rolling-file-name)

Comment: @ColinM No, it is all about formatting, while I am asking about omitting datetime part of filename for the current file which should be much more simple than that.

Comment: @AntonKrouglov I'm looking for the same functionality, have you found solution?

Comment: @MaximKitsenko unfortunately there is no way

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is currently not supported by the `Serilog.Sinks.File` and there are no plans to support it in the short term. You can see a long discussion around this on the link below:

> [Fixed filename with rolling archive files #40](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-file/issues/40)

You can see an initial attempt to add this feature as a separate package (though it's still early days and has known limitations) on this repository: https://github.com/dfacto-lab/serilog-sinks-file

Of course, you can always roll your own version of `Serilog.Sinks.File` that adds the behavior you're looking for.

---

Other, related links:

- [Allow option to keep root log file as most recent #115](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-file/issues/115)
- [Properly rotate log files #667](https://github.com/bitwarden/server/issues/667)

Answer (score 3):

Serilog does not support this feature yet.
You can find the discussion here. There is also a workaround in place :)

https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-file/issues/40